# How to add extra date column in DataFrame by using Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date, datetime, timestamp

I have variable, for example:

`val loadingDate: = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)`

I need to add an extra column by using the value of this variable.

When I try to do this:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

DF.withColumn("dttm", expr(s"$loadingDate.format(formatter)}").cast("timestamp"))
```

I get error like that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException

mismutched input '00' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 11)

==SQL==

2020-01-02 00:00:00

-------------^^^
```

Can I use variables of type LocalDateTime for adding extra columns in Spark? Or do I have to use other types?

I need to get a date from an external system and use this date in Spark. How can I do this the best way? Which types to use?

Comment: Look at the static functions, it might be easier. Sorry, not very familiar with Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your parsed string `val dateString = s"$loadingDate.format(formatter)"` and convert it into Spark `DateType` using `to_date()` function, first of all you have to convert String into literal(or in other words, represent your string as a column), to do so use `lit(dateString)`.

```
val date: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 2, 0,0, 0)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val formattedDate = date.format(formatter).

val dfWithYourDate = df.withColumn("your_date", to_date(lit(formattedDate), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

If you need `TimestampType` instead of `to_date()` use function `to_timestamp()`